# SQL next bigInt for InvoiceID in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I hope someone could help me here,
am working with SQL Server, using 4 tables.

- Invoice
- InvoiceLine
- Ledger
- History

every time I need to create an invoice I need also to generate a sequence number and use it for update or insert to the other tables by using transaction (using wpf - vb.net ado.net Transactions)
SO in other words I need to know the next  Invoice ID and able to use it to the other tables for the insert/update

Please note it will be use in multiple computers so the Invoice ID should not be conflict with another invoice ID when is created

I have read several forums here in stack overflow and there, suggesting that first must be inserted and then retrieve it back and then update any other tables .in my case I need it to use one transaction and commit them all if everything are fine

I also read another approach that SQL can generate a sequence of numbers for example

*NEXT VALUE FOR*  . if something goes wrong the *next value for* will be incremented by 1 and will let behind the fail one.

can someone give me any helpful links or his own idea how can I solve this?

for the time now am query the invoices get the max InvoiceID and increment it by 1 some milliseconds before the execution so am eliminating the case that someone could get the same Invoice ID but again this is not 100% the correct.

sorry for the long description 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from doing the insert into Invoice, read the new ID and the do the insert into the other tables within a transaction.

Identity values will not be reissued in case you do a rollback though. If you use Sequence in Sql Server those numbers will not be reissued either.

If you absolutely need an unbroken series you will have to implement it your self.

Comment: thank for your reply idstam , my requirement is to use a sequence of number (unbroken series) and use it in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sequence feature in sql server.It is similar to the identity increment.you can get the next sequence number by calling the

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[MyTable_Sequence] 
 AS [smallint]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -32768
 MAXVALUE 32767
 CACHE 
GO
```

You can get the value using

```
 NEXT VALUE FOR [SEQUENCE NAME]
```

If you store it in a parameter as below you can use the value anywhere in the scope

```
DECLARE @ID SMALLINT

SET @ID =   NEXT VALUE FOR [SEQUENCE NAME]
```

Refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: hi mindbdev, I have read your suggestion I also check ti with the sql, however this will not work since the (next value for)  will always be incremented by 1 , but if my record fail to insert in the table successfully for any reason then this incremented number for example 1 next time will be 2 and that is wrong from my requirement needs . if the row fails then the next value should still be 1 and not 2. but again any solution should be work for multiuser environment